# call the standard segue by tapping a button

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift2, segue

i've a UITableView with two Columns: a text colomn and an image

[image]

for the textColumn on the left, i use a standarard segue, everytehing is fine...

Now i want to implement the **same action**, when the right button is tapped

i tried it with a new segue *imageDisplay* for the right (image) column

```
    let tapRecognizerImage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("imageAction:"))
    cell.imageButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizerImage)

}

func imageAction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("imageDisplay", sender: self)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        controller.kategorie = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Kategorien
    } else if segue.identifier == "imageDisplay" {
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        controller.kategorie = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Kategorien
    }
}
```

Now in

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
```

i get the error

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is, cause self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! is nil!

Perhaps, there´s a much simpier way ro resolve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `nil` because you do not select a row by taping on an image.
Try to set `cell.imageButton.tag` to `indexPath.row` (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) and use `sender.tag` instead of `indexPath` in `prepareForSegue`.
If you really need an `NSIndexPath` in `prepareForSegue` just create one and set its row to `sender.tag`